# "Heel click" in Spanish

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, solicitud-de-término, sustantivos, palabras-raras

I'm pretty sure that there's a fancy word for *heel click* in Spanish that I can't remember.

(I'm referring to the gesture of joy that's done by performing an aerial click of both heels, just in case you're wondering. If you cannot visualise how it's like, just search for images on your favourite engine.)

I've spent a long time searching and the best I've been able to find is "taconeo" and "taconazo", which aren't THE word (as soon as I see it, I'll recognise it).

Any help will be appreciated because I've come to a dead end.

EDIT. It's more or less like this:

[image]

Comment: isn't "cabriola" ? a dance move ?

Comment: Good point, but all the definitions of _cabriola_ I find appear to involve crossing the feet and not making them "click". It's not only a dance move by definition, but apparent it's usual in _tap dance_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's magic! I've remembered it right now! :/

It was [***zapateta***](http://que-significa.com/significado.php?termino=zapateta) (which is quite a funny word, by the way):

> f. Golpe que se da en el pie o zapato.
>   Brinco que se da chocando los zapatos entre sí:
>   *el niño hacía zapatetas para demostrar su entusiasmo.*
>
> pl. Golpes que se dan con el zapato en el suelo en ciertos bailes.

Answer (score 0):

As always, your mileage may vary. Although *Zapateta* is common in Spain, the definition I read you post, is more akin to a kid *kicking* and screaming as in *throwing a fit*

What you describe in your question would be better understood as ***talonazo*** which is a kind of military/martial move.

It is strongly associated with fascist regimes, though!

https://youtu.be/KD-BNCyJb7Y (check the honor guard relieving shift at 2:25. This is 1980s Santiago de Chile although one could easily assume its a scene from 1920s Germany, complete with Stahlhelms and Hugo-boss inspired uniforms.

It is a decidedly elegant, but not a popular move throughout Spanish speaking countries: its a reminder of the Spanish civil war, or the South American military dictatorships.

Is this the "boot click" you are referring to?

Comment: No. I'm not referring to this one, but thanks for your effort, though. ;) I said *aerial*. I'm going to edit my OP with a picture to make it more visual.

Comment: I can't picture a soldier doing this one. It isn't exactly martial...

Comment: Quite right, my mistake, now I know what you meant. And yes, LOL, can't imagine any soldier, much less uninformed as if about to invade Poland doing that. =)